# Optimizar una consulta SQL muy grande en PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, union

me tocó revisar un código y optimizarlo. El codigo en cuestion genera un informe o reporte en excel, pero se demora demasiado.

Consiste en una consulta de tipo UNION, hace match con varias tablas y campos, depues se recorre mediante un foreach y luego dentro de el se vuelve a correr una consulta mas pequeña que no pondré porque no es relevante.

¿Que pensáis que sea lo mejor para resolver esto? ¿Estaba pensando usar funciones de Postgree o de php?

```
SELECT 
        avs.id_vale_salida,
        avsrd.id_vale_salida_requisicion_detalle,
        abc.numero_clasificacion,
        ard.cantidad,
        avsrd.cantidad as cantidad1,
        abc.descripcion,
        abc.partida,
        aum.des_medida,
        avs.fecha,
        ar.id_proyecto,
        ar.id_empleado_solicita,
        proyectos.id_area,
        avs.tipo_vale,
        avs.gran_catalogo
        from
        almacen_requisicion_detalles as ard,
        almacen_bienes_consumo as abc,
        adquisiciones_unidad_medida as aum,
        almacen_vale_salida_requisicion_detalles as avsrd,
        almacen_vale_salida_requisicion as avsr,
        almacen_vale_salida as avs,
        almacen_vale_salida_seg as avsseg,
        almacen_requisicion as ar,
        proyectos,
        areas 
        where
        avs.id_vale_salida=avsr.id_vale_salida and
        avsr.id_vale_salida_requisicion=avsrd.id_vale_salida_requisicion and
        avsrd.id_almacen_requisicion_detalle=ard.id_almacen_requisicion_detalle and
        ard.id_bien_consumo=abc.id_bien_consumo and
        abc.id_medida=aum.id_medida AND
        avs.id_vale_salida=avsseg.id_vale_salida AND
        avsseg.id_estatus=2 AND
        avsseg.activo=1 AND
        ard.id_almacen_requisicion = ar.id_almacen_requisicion AND
        proyectos.id_proyecto=ar.id_proyecto AND
        areas.id_area=proyectos.id_area
        AND avs.fecha between '2023-08-01' and '2023-08-30'
        AND avs.gran_catalogo NOT IN (1)
        UNION
        (
        SELECT
        avs.id_vale_salida,
        avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido_detalle as id_vale_salida_requisicion_detalle, 
        abc.numero_clasificacion,
        ac.cantidad,
        avspd.cantidad as cantidad1,
        ac.descripcion,
        dr.partida,
        aum.des_medida,
        avs.fecha,
        p.id_proyecto,
        dr.id_empleado_solicita,
        p.id_area,
        avs.tipo_vale,
        avs.gran_catalogo
        FROM
        adquisiciones_cotizacion as ac,
        almacen_altas_consumo_detalles as aacd,
        documento_requisicion_detalles as drd,
        adquisiciones_unidad_medida as aum,
        almacen_vale_salida as avs,
        almacen_vale_salida_pedido as avsp,
        almacen_altas_consumo_comercio as aacc,
        almacen_altas_consumo_detalles_comercio as aacdc,
        almacen_altas_consumo as aac,
        almacen_vale_salida_pedido_detalles as avspd,
        documento_requisicion as dr,
        almacen_bienes_consumo as abc,
        proyectos as p,
        documentos,
        almacen_vale_salida_seg,
        adquisiciones_pedido as ap,
        areas
        WHERE
        avs.id_vale_salida=avsp.id_vale_salida and
        avsp.id_alta_consumo_comercio=aacc.id_alta_consumo_comercio and
        aacc.id_alta_consumo=aac.id_alta_consumo and
        aac.id_alta_consumo=aacd.id_alta_consumo and
        aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle=aacdc.id_alta_consumo_detalle and
        aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle=avspd.id_alta_consumo_detalle and
        avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido=avsp.id_vale_salida_pedido and
        aacdc.id_cotizacion=ac.no_cotizacion and
        ac.id_requisicion_detalle=drd.id_requisicion_detalle and
        aacd.id_medida=aum.id_medida and
        dr.id_requisicion=drd.id_requisicion  and
        aacd.id_bien_consumo=abc.id_bien_consumo and
        p.id_proyecto=documentos.id_proyecto AND
        documentos.id_documento=dr.id_documento and
        almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_vale_salida=avs.id_vale_salida AND
        almacen_vale_salida_seg.activo=1 AND
        almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_estatus=1 and
        p.id_area=areas.id_area and
        aacc.id_pedido=ap.id_pedido and
        ap.id_pedido=ac.id_pedido
        AND avs.fecha between '2023-08-01' and '2023-08-30'
        AND aacd.gran_catalogo NOT IN (1))

        UNION
        (SELECT
        avs.id_vale_salida,
        avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido_detalle as id_vale_salida_requisicion_detalle, 
        abc.id_producto AS numero_clasificacion,
        ac.cantidad,
        avspd.cantidad as cantidad1,
        ac.descripcion,
        dr.partida,
        aum.des_medida,
        avs.fecha,
        p.id_proyecto,
        dr.id_empleado_solicita,
        p.id_area,
        avs.tipo_vale,
        avs.gran_catalogo
        FROM
        adquisiciones_cotizacion as ac,
        almacen_altas_consumo_detalles as aacd,
        documento_requisicion_detalles as drd,
        adquisiciones_unidad_medida as aum,
        almacen_vale_salida as avs,
        almacen_vale_salida_pedido as avsp,
        almacen_altas_consumo_comercio as aacc,
        almacen_altas_consumo_detalles_comercio as aacdc,
        almacen_altas_consumo as aac,
        almacen_vale_salida_pedido_detalles as avspd,
        documento_requisicion as dr,
        control_gran_catalogo as abc,
        proyectos as p,
        documentos,
        almacen_vale_salida_seg,
        adquisiciones_pedido as ap,
        areas
        WHERE
        avs.id_vale_salida=avsp.id_vale_salida and
        avsp.id_alta_consumo_comercio=aacc.id_alta_consumo_comercio and
        aacc.id_alta_consumo=aac.id_alta_consumo and
        aac.id_alta_consumo=aacd.id_alta_consumo and
        aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle=aacdc.id_alta_consumo_detalle and
        aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle=avspd.id_alta_consumo_detalle and
        avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido=avsp.id_vale_salida_pedido and
        aacdc.id_cotizacion=ac.no_cotizacion and
        ac.id_requisicion_detalle=drd.id_requisicion_detalle and
        aacd.id_medida=aum.id_medida and
        dr.id_requisicion=drd.id_requisicion  and
        aacd.id_bien_consumo=abc.id_producto and
        p.id_proyecto=documentos.id_proyecto AND
        documentos.id_documento=dr.id_documento and
        almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_vale_salida=avs.id_vale_salida AND
        almacen_vale_salida_seg.activo=1 AND
        almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_estatus=1 and
        p.id_area=areas.id_area and
        aacc.id_pedido=ap.id_pedido and
        ap.id_pedido=ac.id_pedido
        AND avs.fecha between '2023-08-01' and '2023-08-30'
        AND aacd.gran_catalogo IN (1));
```

despues de esto, se procede a recorrer los resultados con

```
foreach($rst_detalles_seguimiento as $key1){

}
```

Comment: si me dejas un ejemplo minimamente funcional en http://sqlfiddle.com/ a lo mejor te ayude pero por ahora  lo unico que te puedo sugerir es cambiar los union etc por    INNER JOIN y LEFT JOIN ...

Comment: UNION y JOIN son operaciones completamente diferentes

Comment: Un EXPLAIN podría indicarte dónde le duele. Etiqueta tu motor de base de datos.

Comment: Ya puse la etiqueta. probaré usando EXPLAIN. Veré la posibilidad de usar un sqlfiddle aunque esta complejo ya que son bastantes tablas

Comment: Aparte de lo que ya te indican los compañeros, una vez verificado que tu consulta (o modelo de datos) están optimizados, si sigue la lentitud, conviene probar la consulta directamente en el SGBD. A veces la lentitud proviene del código que maneja los datos, no de la consulta en sí misma. No digo que sea el caso, pero es algo a considerar.

Answer (score 1):

Existen un par de problemas con esta consulta.

Para empezar, es probable que los UNION estén ocultando un gran problema al eliminar duplicados. Es común ver que se usa `UNION` cuando se debería usar `UNION ALL`. La diferencia es que el primero elimina los duplicados del resultado mientras que el otro muestra todas las filas. Eso hace que el primero sea una operación más costosa porque tiene que ordenar los datos.

En segundo lugar, la forma de unir las tablas es un estándar obsoleto que oculta otro problema. Me di la libertad de refactorizar el código utilizando los operadores `JOIN` para unir tablas. De esta forma, queda claro que hay tablas que no tienen criterio para unirse con las otras y forman un producto cartesiano que multiplica las filas y genera resultados incorrectos.

```
SELECT avs.id_vale_salida,
    avsrd.id_vale_salida_requisicion_detalle,
    abc.numero_clasificacion,
    ard.cantidad,
    avsrd.cantidad AS cantidad1,
    abc.descripcion,
    abc.partida,
    aum.des_medida,
    avs.fecha,
    ar.id_proyecto,
    ar.id_empleado_solicita,
    proyectos.id_area,
    avs.tipo_vale,
    avs.gran_catalogo
FROM almacen_requisicion_detalles               AS ard     
JOIN almacen_bienes_consumo                     AS abc    ON ard.id_bien_consumo                = abc.id_bien_consumo
JOIN adquisiciones_unidad_medida                AS aum    ON abc.id_medida                      = aum.id_medida
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_requisicion_detalles   AS avsrd  ON ard.id_almacen_requisicion_detalle = avsrd.id_almacen_requisicion_detalle
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_requisicion            AS avsr   ON avsrd.id_vale_salida_requisicion   = avsr.id_vale_salida_requisicion
JOIN almacen_vale_salida                        AS avs    ON avsr.id_vale_salida                = avsr.id_vale_salida
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_seg                    AS avsseg ON avs.id_vale_salida                 = avsseg.id_vale_salida
JOIN almacen_requisicion                        AS ar     ON ard.id_almacen_requisicion         = ar.id_almacen_requisicion
JOIN proyectos                                            ON ar.id_proyecto                     = proyectos.id_proyecto
JOIN areas                                                ON proyectos.id_area                  = areas.id_area
WHERE  avsseg.id_estatus = 2
    AND avsseg.activo = 1
    AND avs.fecha BETWEEN '2023-08-01' AND '2023-08-30'
    AND avs.gran_catalogo NOT IN (1)

UNION
SELECT avs.id_vale_salida,
    avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido_detalle AS id_vale_salida_requisicion_detalle,
    abc.numero_clasificacion,
    ac.cantidad,
    avspd.cantidad AS cantidad1,
    ac.descripcion,
    dr.partida,
    aum.des_medida,
    avs.fecha,
    p.id_proyecto,
    dr.id_empleado_solicita,
    p.id_area,
    avs.tipo_vale,
    avs.gran_catalogo
FROM adquisiciones_cotizacion                   AS ac
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo_detalles             AS aacd  ON 
JOIN documento_requisicion_detalles             AS drd   ON ac.id_requisicion_detalle       = drd.id_requisicion_detalle
JOIN adquisiciones_unidad_medida                AS aum   ON aacd.id_medida                  = aum.id_medida
JOIN almacen_vale_salida                        AS avs   ON 
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_pedido                 AS avsp  ON avs.id_vale_salida              = avsp.id_vale_salida
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo_comercio             AS aacc  ON avsp.id_alta_consumo_comercio   = aacc.id_alta_consumo_comercio
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo_detalles_comercio    AS aacdc ON aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle    = aacdc.id_alta_consumo_detalle 
                                                        AND ac.no_cotizacion                = aacdc.id_cotizacion
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo                      AS aac   ON aacc.id_alta_consumo            = aac.id_alta_consumo 
                                                        AND aacd.id_alta_consumo            = aac.id_alta_consumo
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_pedido_detalles        AS avspd ON aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle    = avspd.id_alta_consumo_detalle 
                                                        AND avsp.id_vale_salida_pedido      = avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido
JOIN documento_requisicion                      AS dr    ON drd.id_requisicion              = dr.id_requisicion 
                                                        AND drd.id_requisicion              = dr.id_requisicion 
JOIN almacen_bienes_consumo                     AS abc   ON aacd.id_bien_consumo            = abc.id_bien_consumo
JOIN proyectos                                  AS p     ON 
JOIN documentos                                          ON p.id_proyecto                   = documentos.id_proyecto 
                                                        AND dr.id_documento                 = documentos.id_documento
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_seg                             ON avs.id_vale_salida              = almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_vale_salida
JOIN adquisiciones_pedido                       AS ap    ON aacc.id_pedido                  = ap.id_pedido 
                                                        AND ac.id_pedido                    = ap.id_pedido
JOIN areas                                               ON p.id_area                       = areas.id_area
WHERE   almacen_vale_salida_seg.activo = 1
    AND almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_estatus = 1
    AND avs.fecha BETWEEN '2023-08-01' AND '2023-08-30'
    AND aacd.gran_catalogo NOT IN (1)
UNION
SELECT avs.id_vale_salida,
    avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido_detalle AS id_vale_salida_requisicion_detalle,
    abc.id_producto AS numero_clasificacion,
    ac.cantidad,
    avspd.cantidad AS cantidad1,
    ac.descripcion,
    dr.partida,
    aum.des_medida,
    avs.fecha,
    p.id_proyecto,
    dr.id_empleado_solicita,
    p.id_area,
    avs.tipo_vale,
    avs.gran_catalogo
FROM adquisiciones_cotizacion                   AS ac
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo_detalles             AS aacd  ON 
JOIN documento_requisicion_detalles             AS drd   ON ac.id_requisicion_detalle       = drd.id_requisicion_detalle
JOIN adquisiciones_unidad_medida                AS aum   ON aacd.id_medida                  = aum.id_medida
JOIN almacen_vale_salida                        AS avs   ON 
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_pedido                 AS avsp  ON avs.id_vale_salida              = avsp.id_vale_salida
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo_comercio             AS aacc  ON avsp.id_alta_consumo_comercio   = aacc.id_alta_consumo_comercio
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo_detalles_comercio    AS aacdc ON aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle    = aacdc.id_alta_consumo_detalle
                                                        AND ac.no_cotizacion                = aacdc.id_cotizacion
JOIN almacen_altas_consumo                      AS aac   ON aacc.id_alta_consumo            = aac.id_alta_consumo 
                                                        AND aacd.id_alta_consumo            = aac.id_alta_consumo
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_pedido_detalles        AS avspd ON aacd.id_alta_consumo_detalle    = avspd.id_alta_consumo_detalle
                                                        AND avsp.id_vale_salida_pedido      = avspd.id_vale_salida_pedido
JOIN documento_requisicion                      AS dr    ON drd.id_requisicion              = dr.id_requisicion
JOIN control_gran_catalogo                      AS abc   ON aacd.id_bien_consumo            = abc.id_producto
JOIN proyectos                                  AS p     ON 
JOIN documentos                                          ON dr.id_documento                 = documentos.id_documento
                                                        AND p.id_proyecto                   = documentos.id_proyecto
JOIN almacen_vale_salida_seg                             ON avs.id_vale_salida              = almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_vale_salida 
JOIN adquisiciones_pedido                       AS ap    ON aacc.id_pedido                  = ap.id_pedido
                                                        AND ac.id_pedido                    = ap.id_pedido
JOIN areas                                               ON p.id_area                       = areas.id_area
WHERE  almacen_vale_salida_seg.activo = 1
    AND almacen_vale_salida_seg.id_estatus = 1
    AND avs.fecha BETWEEN '2023-08-01' AND '2023-08-30'
    AND aacd.gran_catalogo IN (1);
```

Por lo anterior, recomiendo que empieces por unir correctamente las tablas y cambies los `UNION` por `UNION ALL`. Después de eso, se puede optimizar mejor la consulta en caso de ser necesario.

Comment: Agradezco tu valioso tiempo, dejame hacer algunos ajustes en base a lo que sugieres. gracias!